# How to make widget as input variable for my class

Tags: flutter

I want to put `Widget` inside class's input variables. Can I somehow do that?

```
class Karta extends StatelessWidget {

  final int _index;
  final List _list;
  final Widget _widget;
  Karta(this._index,this._list,this._widget);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage("https://dummyimage.com/1080x337/000/fff"),
            fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          )
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(list_mainmenu[_index]),
          subtitle: Text("bong"),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => _widget(_index), // this gives me error!
            ));
          }
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
final Widget _widget;
```

with

```
final _widget;
```

---

Because `Widget` isn't a function, you can't really invoke anything on it. All you need to do is remove `Widget` from your code. And Dart will now infer its type by looking what you're passing.

Comment: I don't think it is a correct way. Because now it can take any value even functions. So if you pass anything other than `Widget` then your Navigator fails.

Comment: @Marat It may not be the right way, but what OP asked is done by this approach. Sometimes there are multiple solutions to a problem.

Comment: Maybe. But what if you or your team member passes function or anything other than Widget?

Comment: @Marat Then you'll have to find a better approach than this, don't create `Karta` like that, (if OP had mentioned his use case, it would have made more sense what needs to be done)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Widget` but you cannot pass `_index` into it. Alternatively, you can use your custom widget instead of `Widget` which takes `_index` as an argument

YourWidget

```
final int _index;
YourWidget(this._index);
```

Karta

```
YourWidget widget;


widget(_index)
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate full `YourWidget` code, how you're going to use it for `index`?

Comment: OP wants to use `index` so I just showed how s/he can pass `index` into his Widget

Comment: Can you tell me what is `YourWidget` here? Does it extend any sort of class? Please update your post, I want to see it.

Comment: It depends on what OP wants. It might either extend `StatefulWidget` or `StatelessWidget`

Comment: All I wanted to show is how to pass `index` into your widget